# Counting printed pages on a network printer

Tags: networking, lubuntu, printing

In my company I have a printer connected to a PC with Lubuntu and this PC is connected to internal network. I would like to make the printer accessible via this PC, however, not just make it a shared printer, but so that

1. everybody has a some sort of account and
2. for each account, PC counts total number of printed pages,

The idea is of course to monitor how much each employee printed.

Is there any neat program to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is CUPS.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/cups.html

for advanced configuration and policies you can look at

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/policies.html